# how prevents trigering of infiniteScroll on up scrolling

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

i implements nginfintescroll library by following this tutorial [click here](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html)

but the event triggered on both down and up scrolling. I want to disable the up scrolling events

Comment: Can you put some code how you use it?

Comment: Also check https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll